# Looking for a half float or quarter float library

Tags: c++, c, assembly, floating-point

I need to store values in a range of about -10000 to 10000. At the range borders, the precision needed is not very high (maybe about 64, I will see how it fits), around zero the precision needs to be 1 or better.

Unfortunately space is *very* limited, not more than 12 bits, less would even be better. So strictly speaking, even [half floats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format) are out. Is there an open source library which handles some very short float formats with short mantissa and exponent length? Like 8 bit mantissa and 3 bit exponent.

Only conversion from/to bigger formats is required, no arithmetic is done.

Comment: With a 3 bits exponent you would have a 128 minimum precision.

Comment: Yes, most likely I will end up cooking something by myself using bitfields. But I am interested in seeing the solutions others had found - if there are any.

Comment: @xanatos: only if you stick to a radix of 2.  If you switch to a radix of 10, he only needs 9 bit mantissa, 2 bit radix.  (Accuracy of 39 near 10000)

Comment: @drhirsch: just occurred to me, you can have a library that only uses 12 bits of precision, but you can't store them as is, as it will be padded (probably to 16).  You'll have to bit-twiddle to store it in a 12 bit field.

Comment: @MooingDuck I am fully aware of that :-) I store several of these values in one bucket, which is aligned at a byte address.

Comment: This question would also be welcome on [scicomp](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps [μ-law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-law_algorithm) or [A-law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-law_algorithm) could be useful for you.

Comment: oh, interesting thought.  You should expand on this answer.  A lot.

Comment: If he is precise to nearest 1 from 0-12, precision 2 from 13-25, precision 3 from 26-38... thats precision 39 from 9671-10139, and it fits in 9 bits! (leaving 10th bit for sign)  I have no idea how to do the math for this though.

Comment: Very interesting. I did implement something smiliar with only 4 ranges in my old code. Now I will try to find an efficient generalization or abstraction and see what ratio of ranges/values fits best.

Comment: There is a lot you can try with (natural) logs, but this may be a good place to start.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not doing any computation, then there's barely a need for a library.  `frexp`, `ldexp` and some bit-twiddling should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

We use libHalf which comes with [openexr](http://www.openexr.com/downloads.html). I am not a big fan of it since the code quality isn't exactly stellar (though it also isn't seriously broken). Look for the directory named `Half` in the extracted sources -- it should be standalone.

Answer (score 1):

Extrapolating from Jens Björnhager's answer, I got this:

```
double from_storage(unsigned short bits) { //only lowest 10 bits read
        double a = bits&0x1FF;
        a /= 5.11967985;
        a = a*a;
        return double(bits&0x200 ? -a : a);
}

unsigned short to_storage(double a) { //only lowest 10 bits set/relevant
        assert(a<=10000.0);
        assert(a>=-10000.0);
        if (a >= 0) {
                a = std::pow(a, .5); // inverse of number in from_storage
                a *= 5.11967985;
                unsigned short b = ((unsigned short)(a));
                assert((b&0x200)==0);
                return b;
        } else {
                a = std::pow(-a, .5);
                a *= 5.11967985;
                unsigned short b = ((unsigned short)(a));
                assert((b&0x200)==0);
                return b | 0x200;
        }
}
```

as demonstrated at http://ideone.com/DLTUn.  This can hold each of the values between -10 and 10 uniquely, and the top values are only 39 apart.  (There's also 3 values between 0 and 1). Someone more mathy could probably get the positive and negative to more of a "two's compliment" format, which would cut the `to_storage` code in half.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I think I will use some variant of µ-Law (which is very similar to a quarter float) extended to 11 or 12 bits. I need to store several 10^9 of these values (the more, the better), thats the main reason I want to save every bit. Speed of conversion is another concern - pow is most likely to slow, but some table driven approach will do.

Comment: @drhirsch: this works along the same lines as µ-Law, except with a smooth curve.  A table based approach might be faster, but would be more complicated.  I think the table is the better answer in all.